# Python 3 Bitwise operator issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, bitwise-operators

I'm encountering issues when trying to perform bitwise operators. I know the cause, I'm just not sure how to resolve it.

Essentially, I'm able to pass through hardcoded bytes and get the operators to work, however my existing code gathers data from text files, and converts various data types to hex string and then writes it out to a binary file using binascii.a2b_hex()

I'm trying to perform function that will use bitwise operators on the segment of bytes to calculate a checksum.

How am I able to convert a hex-string `"EF", "4E", "AC", "4A", "7D", "22"` to essentially look like `0xEF, 0x4E, 0xAC, 0x4A, 0x7D, 0x22`

I have tried to use the binascii.a2b_hex() function on that item within the array of bytes, but it returns b'EF' and not 0xEF

Additionally, I've also tried to use str.encode() and it still doesn't translate it properly..

Comment: You can prepend the string `'0x'` using the `+` operator.

Comment: So you are essentially asking how to read hex, the question is not related to bitwise operators at all? Or specific to Python 3...

Comment: `0xEF` is just yet another representation of `239`, which is just yet another representation of `0b11101111`, which is yet another representation of `0357`, which is yet another representation of... What you should care about is the _type_ of data, not its representations (however, the latter are indeed useful). All of the above are of type `int`, for example, and they  do support bitwise operations.

Comment: If you want the number `0xEF` instead of the string `'0xEF'`, you can just use the python `int(n, 16)` function (where 16 is the base; hexadecimal)

Just search "python convert hex string to number" on google.

Comment: I'm likely misunderstanding how to word this. I'm parsing data out of a text file, which contains ascii text. Doing conversions from the ascii to ints and floats, then converting those values into hex to write out to a binary file. I need to calculate a checksum, and when I try to pass through my array of bytes, I get an "unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'int' and 'bytes'"